# Disable Network connection in Windows PE

Tags: networking, boot, automation, windows-pe

I am generating a WindowsPE boot stick with the Microsoft Automation Installation Kit 10 (host is Windows 10) for a `amd64` target platform.

Because i dont need network connections from within the WinPE, id like to completely and securely disable them.

I have a rough understanding of the [WinPE bootchain](https://slightlyovercomplicated.com/2016/11/07/windows-pe-startup-sequence-explained/) so i know that i can pass a [configuration file](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/wpeinit-and-startnetcmd-using-winpe-startup-scripts) to `wpeinit` which would allow me to disable the network. The [10 year old mystery](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/32840d51-fdc6-42d1-9032-90d6e7136263/unattendxml-file-settings-for-network-initialization?forum=itprovistadeployment) remains: how would that file have to be structured? A minimal example of

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<unattend xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:unattend">
    <EnableNetwork>false</EnableNetwork>
</unattend>
```

does not throw an error message but also does not work. Its called from within `startnet.cmd` like this:

`wpeinit -unattend:"%SystemRoot%\system32\Unattend.xml"`

allthough i also [have](http://reboot.pro/topic/3033-winpeshlini-and-startnetcmd/) [seen](http://andrewt.com/2009/09/21/speeding-up-winpe-boot-time.html) `wpeinit /unattend: ...`.

The `%SystemRoot%\system32\wpeinit.log` logfile states:

> 2017-08-02 13:26:16.061, Info      WPEINIT is processing the unattend file [X:\windows\system32\Unattend.xml]
>
> ...
>
> 2017-08-02 13:26:16.295, Info      ==== Initializing Network Access and Applying Configuration ====
>   2017-08-02 13:26:16.295, Info      No EnableNetwork unattend setting was specified; the default action for this context is to enable networking support.

The [provided](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms912214(v=winembedded.10).aspx) [examples](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732280(v=ws.10).aspx) dont help me much either, i think this might be for automated installation, not configuration.

I verify that networks are disabled via the following commands

```
netsh interface ipv4 show interfaces
netsh interface ipv6 show interfaces
```

There is the possibility of [disabling the connection via netsh](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/7b398025-55f6-416e-a5cf-5ca44fac3e6b/winpe-disableing-and-reenabling-a-wired-ethernet-connection-to-renegotiate-ethernet-speed?forum=w7itproinstall) like

```
netsh interface set interface "Local Area Connection" DISABLED
```

but im afraid that WinPE might have tried to access a DHCP already or was reachable via network for a short period of time.

So how can a networkless WinPE be achieved? Thanks!

Is not calling `wpeinit` from `startnet.cmd` an option since i need devices initialized with their drivers? [Some posts](http://www.msfn.org/board/topic/163425-how-to-not-have-network-loaded/) suggest so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heureka! I was so close that i finally managed to get it working ([one reference](http://andrewt.com/2009/09/21/speeding-up-winpe-boot-time.html) in the question actually had the answer, only for `x86`).

Important lessons learned:

- target [plattform is important](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/e7b53d34-5ed9-49b9-bacf-387750e2b306/components-with-processorarchitectureamd64-and-processorarchitecturex86-in-one-unattendxml?forum=w7itproinstall) for settings
- `components` are required, see [their documentation](https://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/library/cc722132(v=ws.10).aspx), especially the [`Microsoft-Windows-Setup`](https://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/library/cc749585(v=ws.10).aspx) one which allows `<EnableNetwork>` configuration

Without further ado, this is the `Unattend.xml` which gets copied by the generation process to `%SystemRoot%\system32`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<unattend xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:unattend">
    <settings pass="windowsPE">
        <component name="Microsoft-Windows-Setup" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS" processorArchitecture="AMD64">
            <EnableNetwork>false</EnableNetwork>
        </component>
    </settings>
    <cpi:offlineImage cpi:source="" xmlns:cpi="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:cpi" />
</unattend>
```

called via the modified `startnet.cmd`

```
wpeinit /unattend="%SystemRoot%\system32\Unattend.xml"
```

which leads to the following log entry:

> 2017-08-02 14:51:20.747, Info      WPEINIT is processing the unattend file [X:\windows\system32\Unattend.xml]
>
> ...
>
> 2017-08-02 14:51:20.982, Info      ==== Initializing Network Access and Applying Configuration ====
>
> 2017-08-02 14:51:20.982, Info      Networking support will not be enabled.
>
> 2017-08-02 14:51:20.982, Info      STATUS: SUCCESS (0x00000001)

**ATTENTION**: the sole existance of the file in the `System32` folder leads to its evaluation. So the parameter to `wpeinit` is actually not needed if the file resides at that location.